# How optimized are sub-queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

My question is long but simple. I have queries of the following kind:

```
select obj from table where condition1 and obj in (
select obj from table where condition2 and obj in (
select obj from table where condition3 and obj in (
...
)))
```

This query takes a very long time. I am afraid that MySQL performs this query in the following way (for simplicity let's consider just one sub-query):

```
select obj from table1 where condition1 and obj in (select obj from table2 where condition2)
```

The MySQL goes through rows of the table 1. If `condition1` is fulfilled it starts a loop over the object from the set obtained by the sub-query. If there is a considered object, it is added to the "final" list of objects.

My problem is that the above example has a loop in a loop. And if I have two sub-queries I have a loop in a loop in a loop. If every loop has about 10 000 cycles, I have a disaster.

My solution is to find n sets (every set corresponds to one `select`). Then I make a loop over every set independently (so, I do not have loops in loops). Something like that.

```
dictionary = []
for (elem in set1) {
   dictionary[elem] += 1
}
for (elem in set2) {
   dictionary[elem] += 1
}
for (elem in set3) {
   dictionary[elem] += 1
}
```

Then I make one more loop over all elements of the `dictionary` and select only those keys that were found in all sets:

```
finalSet = []
for (elem in dictionary) {
   if (dictionary[elem]==numberOfSets) {
      finalSet.add(elem)
   }
}
```

So, my question is MySQL is optimized in a way I want it to be optimized (above described way). Or it produce loops in loops in loops....

**ADDED**

I just thought that may be I can achieve the desired optimization by reformulation of my query. Instead of:

```
select obj from table where condition1 and obj in (
select obj from table where condition2 and obj in (
select obj from table where condition3 and obj in (
...
)))
```

I should write:

```
select obj from table where condition1
and obj in (select obj from table where condition2)
and obj in (select obj from table where condition3)
...
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subquery-restrictions.html

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPLAIN to see how MySQL executes the query and take a look at JOIN's to rewrite the query.

```
SELECT
  t1.obj 
FROM 
  table1 AS t1
    JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t1.obj = t2.obj AND condition2)
WHERE 
  t1.condition1
```

Indexes on the obj-fields will speed things up, check EXPLAIN.

Answer (score -1):

Sub query is not too good for optimization. avoid subs queries for any application if it can use another way. you better use this following queries:

select t1.obj 
from table t1
inner join table t2 on  t1.obj = t2.obj 
and  t2.condition='condition'
inner join table t3 on t3.obj = t1.obj
and t3.condition='Condition'

Comment: Subqueries can be very handy and can be optimized by the database optimizer. MySQL isn't too smart with subqueries, but that's still no reason the avoid subqueries for any application. Use them when you need them and let your database work for you.

Comment: ohh yes DBMS can handle sub queries and optimized it. but you must know if you have another way for your queri don't use sub queries because in every database execution plan it is not to good. thanks